# Moving button in application dynamically

Tags: android

```
 public void changeposition (int button){
    int whichPos = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
    if(button == 1){
        switch(whichPos) {
            case 1: dirup.setPadding(0, 0, 284, 128);
            case 2: dirup.setPadding(0, 0, 156, 88);
            case 3: dirup.setPadding(0, 0, 24, 128);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Relative layout and I have 2 buttons which can move to 3 different locations each with random chance. How can I do it in Java code, the code above does nothing almost, it just makes the text inside my button disappear but leave it on the same place.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDirection"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circlered"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:text="@string/direction"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="156dp" />
```

This is how the button is defined in XML now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set the padding larger than the size of the widget (in your case 70dp * 70dp) the button have not enough space for the text.

in your xml you specify margin which does not change the view bounds and is dependent on the outside view.

to update the margin of a view you need to manipulate the LayoutParams.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) dirup.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
dirup.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I got error when using that approach `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams`

Comment: that means you are not using a RelativeLayout as you mentioned.
the LayoutParams depends on the parent view

Comment: Um, you are right, my mistake I use ConstraintLayout, should I change to Relative or I can do it in this layout as well ?

Comment: this highly depends on your use case. every Layout has its own pros and cons.
params like layout_alignParentRight="true" only work on a RelativeLayout. 
the equivalent of ConstraintLayout would be app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

Comment: with the ConstraintLayout you need to cast the LayoutParams to
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Ok, I changed to RelativeLayout now there is no error, but the buttons stay on the same location `switch(whichPos) {
                case 1:  params.setMargins(0, 40, 10, 0); dirup.setLayoutParams(params);
                break;
                case 2: params.setMargins(0, 20, 40, 0); dirup.setLayoutParams(params);
                break;`